# i can not set video duration in Zoom & Pan with Fade In/Out Transition

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg. i am doing Zoom & Pan with Fade In/Out Transition on image to make video i used [this](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-video-slideshow-scripts/blob/master/advanced_scripts/zoom_in_and_pan_with_fade_in_out.sh) script, but this is for 4 image and i want to only for single image so i have tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -filter_complex "\
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=w='if(gte(iw/ih,1280/720),-1,1280)':h='if(gte(iw/ih,1280/720),720,-1)',crop=1280:720,setsar=sar=1/1,format=rgba,split=2[stream1out1][stream1out2];\
[stream1out1]trim=duration=1,select=lte(n\,30),split=2[stream1in][stream1out];\
[stream1out2]trim=duration=2,select=lte(n\,60)[stream1];\
[stream1in]fade=t=in:s=0:n=30[stream1fadein];\
[stream1out]fade=t=out:s=0:n=30[stream1fadeout];\
[stream1fadein][stream1][stream1fadeout]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,scale=1280*5:-1,zoompan=z='min(pzoom+0.002,2)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':s=1280x720 ,format=yuv420p[video]" -map [video] -vsync 2 -async 1 -rc-lookahead 0 -g 0 -profile:v main -level 42 -c:v libx264 -r 30 df.mp4
```

It works fine but it generate 4 second video. So i'm confused about how to set video duration in this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.jpg \
       -vf "scale=w='if(gte(iw/ih,1280/720),-1,1280*5)':h='if(gte(iw/ih,1280/720),720*5,-1)',\
            crop=1280*5:720*5,setsar=1,\
            zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.002,2)':d=X:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':s=1280x720,\
            fade=in:s=0:n=25,fade=out:s=X-25:n=25,format=yuv420p" \
       -c:v libx264 -profile:v main df.mp4
```

Replace `X` in zoompan and fade out with the number of frames you want. The stream fps is 25, so duration is X/25 in seconds.